# applying the XPath function 'substring-after'

Tags: xpath

from the given html :

```
 <span class="flag_16 left_16 armenia_16_left"> First League</span>
```

how i can get the (armenia) string only or at least (armenia_16_left).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are strings `flag_16` and `left_16` constant values?

Comment: yes @KirillPolishchuk they are constant values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(/span /@class, ' '), ' '), '_')
```

**In XPath 2.0 one can simply use**:

```
tokenize(tokenize(/span /@class, ' ')[last()], '_')[1]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  "<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(/span /@class, ' '), ' '), '_')
   "/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<span class="flag_16 left_16 armenia_16_left"> First League</span>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result is copied to the output:**

```
"armenia"
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document** (above):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  "<xsl:sequence select=
   "tokenize(tokenize(/span /@class, ' ')[last()], '_')[1]"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**again the same correct result is produced**:

```
"armenia"
```

Comment: waw great answer thank you @Dimitre Novatchev you are the best.